# to call Controller of one project from other project's controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am using asp.net Mvc3
I have 2 controllers in two different projects.

HomeController in HomeProject and 
WorkController in WorkProject

i need to call Work controller and its view from Home Project's Home Controller.

Something similar to:

```
  public ActionResult Home()
  {
     ViewBag.work = "Work/work/";
     return View(ViewBag.work);
  }
```

But don't know how exactly to do it

can somebody help with this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it using what's provided to you by the mvc framework (Html.Action etc.). The framework was not designed to handle this scenario (nor should it).

You can treat it as an external link, provided you are willing to hardcode the address of the work server:

```
public ActionResult Home()
  {
     Response.Redirect("http://workserver.com/work/work");
  }
```

By the way, if you're asking this, you're doing something wrong. (Have you tried using areas?)

Comment: So this means i can not directly redirect to some other project's controller??

Comment: Not using something like RedirectToAction, no.

Comment: :How can i deal with this??any idea how can i get the view since the RedirectToAction redirect to that controller but does not find the view associated with it.

Comment: using Response.Redirect is not ok?

Comment: :using Response.Redirect i can directly go to the view 
bbut i want to perform some operations in action and then take it to the view...in this case how can i work it??

Comment: Exactly the same. The url is bound to an Action which displays the view, not the other way around. You can't get to a view without passing through an action first.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11337/discussion-between-priya77-and-linkerro)

Answer (score 0):

If your two projects run as a single web app. you can just use

```
return RedirectToAction("Action", "Work")
```

Which will redirect you to the "Action" action of the "Work" controller.
Note that you cannot 'call' a controller - but rather an action on a controller.

Comment: Its going to the appropriate view but gives an error saying "The view 'work' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations."

Comment: How do you know it's going to the appropriate view then? Again - you can only redirect to an action, not to a controller! Does the action you redirect to has a view defined?

Comment: I Sorry....I mean its going to appropriate action"Work" but its not showing the View associated with that action:(

Comment: Which code does that? your version or the RedirectToAction method? Do you have a view for your Work Action?

Comment: return RedirectToAction("work","work");

I have view assosciated with the action called "work"

Comment: hm, interesting... are you using areas? That should not matter for the view but you may try to pass the area too(as a third parameter of RedirectToAction) like this new { area = "MyArea" }

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11305/discussion-between-priya77-and-bond)